# Parsing command line arguments as an AST in C

Tags: c, parsing, command-line, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm wondering what's the best way to parse command line arguments in order to build a binary AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) from them in order to execute it later on.

For example, lets say I have a program to tests environment variables values, and print the result as well as some other information on stdout. I would call it like so in my bash terminal:

```sh
bash$ ./myprogram "MyAwesomeTest" -iszero var1 -o -isnotzero var2 -a -iszero var3 -isnotzero var4
Testing: MyAwesomeTest
Equivalent notation: var1 == 0 || var2 != 0 && var3 == 0 && var4 != 0
Result: True
```

where :

- the first argument is not associated to the tests and is just the name of the test we want to print
- `varN` are environment variables names I want to use.
- `-iszero` tells the program to check if the following environment variable value is equal to 0
- `-isnotzero` tells the program to check if the following environment variable value is not equal to 0
- `-a` is the `AND` operator which has the priority or `OR` and which can be omitted (see: `-iszero var3 -isnotzero var4` is equivalent to `-iszero var3 -a -isnotzero var4`)
- `-o` is the `OR` operator

As written on the output, this call is equivalent of the following test : `var1 == 0 || var2 != 0 && var3 == 0 && var4 != 0`. Thus, it would be parsed as bellow :

```
                  OR
         ________/  \________
        /                    \
   var1 == 0                 AND
                    ________/   \________
                   /                     \
              var2 != 0                  AND
                                ________/   \________
                               /                     \
                          var3 == 0              var4 != 0
```

I think the best way to build the AST would be to use structures :

```c
struct Exp {
    char *varName;
    enum {
        ISZERO = 0,
        ISNOTZERO
    } test;
};

struct Node {
    enum {
        AND = 0,             // When we encounter a -a or 2 expression side by side
        OR,                  // When we encounter a -o
        EXP                  // When we encounter a test such as `-iszero var1`
    } operator;
    struct Node *leftChild;
    struct Node *rightChild;
    struct Exp *exp;         // NULL if the node is a AND or OR
};
```

Then, I only have to run a DFS (Depth-First Search) on the tree to execute the wanted command. However, I don't know how to optimally parse the command line. The lexer is kind of already done as the `argv` argument of the `main` function will have all tokens already as an array. So do you have any idea for the parsing part please ?

PS: *The example here is very specific. Ideally I want to have something that can treat any `-option value` as an `Exp` node, and not only tests on environment variables. As said on the example, I want this parsing to start after the first argument, but this is just a matter of removing the first 2 elements of `argv` from the `main` function.*

Comment: I know I can use `getopt` to get each time the argument and its option but I'm really confused about using it with the AST building

Comment: you may need some form of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm.
You need to maintain a stack of already parsed trees, initially empty or with a sentinel. Process symbols sequentially. At each step depending on the "type" of next symbol  and the "type" of the the tree at the top on the stack some action is taken. Like modifying the top of the stack or consuming the input symbol.

Comment: @tstanisl I read this algorithm, but I don't know how I should deal with the `AND` operator when it's omitted.

Comment: Treat OR as addition and AND as multiplication